# In google play can production roll out and beta version have same version?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have uploaded my application on google play store under beta testing rollout for test purpose to find out if there are impersonation kind of issues.It got published. Now I have a very minor change in my application and would not like to unnecessarily change the version. So can I sign the apk and directly publish it on production .And what will happen to this beta production,anyway I do not wish to retain it,Or should I again upload it with new version on beta test and publish it to production? Any help in which should be the proper procedure is appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to publish the same version code twice to the same release agent. BETA can have versioncode 1 for example and then Production can have versioncode 1, But you can not rebuild and release versioncode 1 again. It will not allow it.

Yes you can release two completely different builds to release vs beta and have both be version 1, but you are creating ambiguity.

BETA users will always have the latest versioncode app whether it comes from BETA or Release, so in this scenario it will likely default to production app as it will assume that BETA was promoted to production due to matching version code. Hope that makes sense.

Also, you do not have to change your version String so if you are going out as 1.00 you can still leave it as 1.00. This is the version string that you show to the user and name the release, you can reuse that as many times are you want, The version code is an arbitrary hidden integer value that google play makes you supply so it knows if it is newer or not. It is not visible to the user other, they will see your version String.

Comment: I mean the version number,  so basically if I understand you correctly, even if I publish it directly to production with same version number without going through the beta route,users will still get the access to beta version ? Or is it that I just cannot do it.

Comment: Yaa, version code is not visible to users, right. You can increase the versionCode any keep the versionName same as before.

Comment: Yes BETA user will get whichever one is newer. If you have versionCode 3 in Production and only versionCode 2 in BETA, then your BETA users will get versionCode 3.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by version. There is a version string which may be the same and there is a version number which must be different.

Comment: Yes I mean version number.

Answer (score 1):

> I sign the apk and directly publish it on production. And what will happen to this beta production? Anyway I do not wish to retain it. Should I again upload it with new version on beta test and publish it to production?

For your new build, increase the the `versionCode` to 1 more than the previous release's `versionCode`. Directly publish that to production. The version in the beta phase will by shadowed by the production version. Anyone having the beta app will see an Update, wherein they can update to the production version. In your Beta section on `App Releases` section, it will show like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank much for the solution.But I simply do not want to retain the beta app,No one has it downloaded as of now. I just want my this version to be available. But anyway if I need to increase the version number, what is the harm in updating the beta application and then publishing it to production. :)